# Verilog (register delay or mistake in code?)

Tags: verilog

I am trying to study Verilog
and I got problem with my code:
the problem is when I trying to add my numbers like
first value clk> second value clk> 3rd value clk> 4th value clk>and here supposed to be my average value BUT for some unknown reason I need to press clock 2 times AGAIN to get averege value
and I don't know why. (I think there is a problem in my code with avereger)
why I have such delay
my avereger must get 4 - 10 bits numbers and show me the averege of it (on my leds)

Here is my code 
and I am including my vector form [

[image]

]

```
module avereger (data_in,Led1,Led2,Led3,clk,rst);
input clk,rst;  
input [9:0]data_in;  
output[6:0] Led1,Led2,Led3; 
reg [9:0] data[3:0];  
reg [11:0] sum,avg_reg; 
always @ (posedge clk)
begin
if(rst==1'b1) 
begin  //all values will be 0 
data[0]<=0;
data[1]<=0;
data[2]<=0;
data[3]<=0;      
sum<=0; 
avg_reg<=0; 
end
else
begin 
data[3]<=data[2];
data[2]<=data[1];
data[1]<=data[0];
data[0]<=data_in;
sum<= data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3]; 
avg_reg<=sum[11:2]; 
end
end
decoder_driver BCD(avg_reg,Led1,Led2,Led3); 
endmodule

module decoder_driver(A,Led1,Led2,Led3);
input [9:0] A; 
output [6:0] Led1,Led2,Led3;
reg [3:0] B,C,D; 
wire [3:0] wireB,wireC,wireD; 
assign wireB=B; 
assign wireC=C;
assign wireD=D;
display1  HUN(wireB,Led1); 
display1  TEN(wireC,Led2); 
display1  ONE(wireD,Led3); 
always @ (A)
begin
B=A/7'd100; 
C=A%7'd100/7'd10; 
D=A%7'd100%7'd10;
end 
endmodule

module display1 (a,Led);
input [3:0] a;
output [6:0] Led; 
reg [6:0] Led; 
always @ (a)
begin
case(a)
4'b0000: Led <= 7'b1000000; //0
4'b0001: Led <= 7'b1111001; //1
4'b0010: Led <= 7'b0100100; //2
4'b0011: Led <= 7'b0110000; //3
4'b0100: Led <= 7'b0011001; //4
4'b0101: Led <= 7'b0010010; //5
4'b0110: Led <= 7'b0000010; //6
4'b0111: Led <= 7'b1111000; //7
4'b1000: Led <= 7'b0000000; //8
4'b1001: Led <= 7'b0010000; //9
4'b1010: Led <= 7'b0001110; //F
default: Led <= 7'b1111111; //-
endcase
end
endmodule
```

Answer (score 1):

The reason the code is taking 6 total cycles instead of 4 is because calculating `sum` and `avg_reg` takes a cycle each, thus combined with the 4 cycles needed to shift in the 4 data items, and you get 6 cycles.

If you watch what happens during simulation, you'll notice shifting in the 4 items takes 4 cycles as expected. However, `sum` is, at the edge the 4th value is take into `data[0]`, the sum of the first third items and whatever was in `data[4]` which is probably all zeroes if you've just done a reset. And `avg_reg` is the value of `sum` from right before the edge shifted over twice. On the next cycle `sum` becomes correct and then the cycle after that `avg_reg` becomes correct.

If you want to remove these cycles, you can simply have `sum` determined combinationally and don't really need `avg_reg` at all:

```
module avereger (data_in,Led1,Led2,Led3,clk,rst);
  input clk, rst;  
  input [9:0] data_in;  
  output[6:0] Led1,Led2,Led3; 

  reg [9:0] data[3:0];  
  wire [11:0] sum;

  always @ (posedge clk) begin
    if(rst==1'b1) begin  //all values will be 0 
      data[0]<='0;
      data[1]<='0;
      data[2]<='0;
      data[3]<='0;       
    end
    else begin 
      data[3]<=data[2];
      data[2]<=data[1];
      data[1]<=data[0];
      data[0]<=data_in;
    end
  end

  // Find sum combinationally
  assign sum = data[0] + data[1] + data[2] + data[3];

  // Do >>2 here
  decoder_driver BCD(.A(sum[11:2]),
                     .Led1(Led1),
                     .Led2(Led2),
                     .Led3(Led3)); 

endmodule
```

Side note, you should avoid writing your own sensitivity lists as its very easy to make mistakes, use `always @(*)` instead of `always @(A)` in your other modules.